# Write list of tuples to csv file keep columns consistent

Tags: python, file, csv, tuples

I am crawling a website with beautifulsoup, half of the page has regular data, X # of fields each having one value, the second half has Y # of fields each with a variable number of values (lots of times just one value, other times any number of values).

The thing that is troubling me is how to write this data to a csv file with consistent number of columns (that way each column will always relate to a single data point... name, address, age - whatever). I am using the csv library to write a csv at the end of my script, I usually just call various lists and their values to populate my csv in a consistent way.

```
writer.writerow([section_defendant[0], section_defendant[1], section_defendant[2], section_defendant[3], section_defendant[4], section_defendant[5], section_defendant[6], section_defendant[7], section_defendant[8], section_defendant[9], section_defendant[10], section_defendant[11], section_defendant[12], section_defendant[13], section_defendant[14], entry_tuple, section_sentence[0], section_sentence[1], section_sentence[2], section_sentence[3], section_sentence[4], bond[0], bond[1], bond[2], bond[3]])
```

The way I store the information from the fields with variable number of entries is by using tuples within a list so my variable entry_tuple often looks like:

```
entry_tuple = [(a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h), (i, j, k, l)]
```

So value a, e, and i, are all the same field say - "charges" - and b, f, and j are all the same field "date" - that is the date relating to a different charge. . .

I know I can use two for loops to get the information out my list of tuples, but the variable entry_tuple may look like this on the next page:

```
entry_tuple2 = [(a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h)]
```

If I write all of those values to file the second row of my CSV is going to have 4 less columns than my first!

I was thinking about going to R to do the analysis side of this project, but also considered using NumPy/Scipy or panda... I just need to get this data written out to a file that I can then read back in during my analysis...

Can I just print the tuple to the single column and then parse it back into some other data structure when I am using python or R as my stats workbench? What data structure should I be using to hold this stuff in memory while doing my stats... I was hoping to keep it simple and just have columns to do frequency distributions, medians sets etc.

Comment: Do you know how long the maximum number of fields is when you have done the processing/scraping (you should - obviously)? Just create tuples of empty string `''` to "pad" the data and keep everything aligned.

Comment: Hey Oliver - this is a good point, I had thought about this, figure out the max number of values, and just pad as you say and end up with a lot of empty columns. I guess I'd need to modify the script to keep track of what is the max value... I don't know if I want to crawl 100,000 pages to get that value, perhaps I just need to do some kind of sampling and use the max of those results. Any input as to what the best sampling methodology would be?

Comment: Did you consider adding the variable length list to the end of the lines in the csv file rather than somewhere in the middle? I have a script that does it like that. That way you never need to know the amount of columns beforehand and most tools that process csv files can handle this situation better.

Comment: Another good point, I appreciate you taking a look at my post and giving me some no nonsense guidance. I think what's happened is I've run into the classic "one to many" problem... it seems like using some relational database would be the standard approach... too bad I don't know much about these!